# (winapi) Is there a way to change the Scale of a Bitmap using the TransparentBlt function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making my first game with winapi.
While developing the game, I wanted to load and use a Bitmap image, so I used the `TransparentBlt` function.
I succeeded in displaying the bitmap image on the screen, but I am not sure how to adjust the scale.

```
TransparentBlt(_dc
        , (int)(vPos.x - (float)(Width / 2))
        , (int)(vPos.y - (float)(Height / 2))
        , Width, Height
        , m_pImage->GetDC()
        , 0, 0, Width, Height
        , RGB(255, 0, 255));
```

What should I do to adjust the scale in the code above?

Comment: If the source and destination rectangles are not the same size, the source bitmap is stretched to match the destination rectangle. [TransparentBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-transparentblt)

Comment: Also see [Scaling an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/scaling-an-image) example which *demonstrates all four of the stretch modes available with the StretchBlt function.*

Answer (score 1):

Scale can be adjusted by multiplying the values ​​of the parameters wDest and hDest of the TransparentBlt() function.

There is also a way to solve it using the BitBlt() function. Similarly, the BitBlt() function can be scaled by multiplying by a value. If it still doesn't work, please leave a comment.

Comment: BitBlt doesn't support stretching.